# UITableViewCell doesn't format properly initially

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and it used to work fine, but i've upgraded to xcode 8 and I'm still using Swift 2.3 and only just started to notice this problem, so I'm not 100% sure when it started to occur.

I am configuring a cell and all it does is make a label circular and place a number inside it, with a name next to it. It should look like this:

[image]

However when the screen initially loads, the circular label is missing. If I scroll down the tableView though and the row leaves the screen, when I scroll back and it becomes in focus again the label appears. The same with the accessory, if I click to edit the row and then return the circle label is generated. Why doesn't it work on the initial load?

Here is the custom code of the UITableViewCell:

```
func circleLabels(label: UILabel, hex: String){
    label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width / 2
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func configureForPlayer(player: Player) {
    playerName.text = player.name
    jerseyLabel.text = String(player.jersey)
    circleLabels(jerseyLabel, hex: "#6470FF")
}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PlayerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
    let player = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Player
    cell.configureForPlayer(player)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ?

Comment: @Marcio of course, I've added. Not sure why it stopped doing it initially

Comment: My guess is that `label.frame` has not yet been set when `circleLabels` is called for the first time. Once it has been drawn and `label.frame` has an actual size then the code starts working as expected. If I'm right putting a constant instead of `label.frame.size.width / 2` should fix the issue.

Comment: @Marcio That seemed to work. Do you want to put an answer to my Q and i'll mark it correct. My label is 44x44 so you know

Comment: Sure thanks :) If you have a constant for the size you can setup `label.layer` directly on interface builder (see http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `label.frame` has not yet been set when `circleLabels` is called for the first time. Once it has been drawn and `label.frame` has an actual size then the code starts working as expected. If I'm right putting a constant instead of `label.frame.size.width / 2` should fix the issue.